# VPN connects but still no Internet on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vpn, openvpn

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and used to connect to airvpn via openvpn and everything always worked quiet well. But now I had to buy a new router, which is a EuroDocsiss router, and it seems that vpn does not work behind this thing. When I connect in the terminal via openvpn everything works just fine and I get "Initialization Sequence Completed" but when I try to connect to any site nothing works. Does anyone have any suggestions how to nail down the problem?

I use VPN to have some privacy while surfing, so solutions like this:
[OpenVPN connecting but no internet access on Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655806/openvpn-connecting-but-no-internet-access-on-ubuntu-14-04-16-04)
do not count, I guess.

I am far from being a crack in handling ubuntu and stuff alike so please be patient with me :)

Thanks for the help!

Here are some terminal outputs that might be helpful?!

This is without vpn connection:

```
    sterome@Sterome:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:eb:38:c7  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:17605 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17605 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2395916 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:2395916 (2.3 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:36:dd:c3:34:1c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:2450:103a:a6a:5c97:d6ce:4d4a:59e/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:2450:103a:a6a:6236:ddff:fec3:341c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6236:ddff:fec3:341c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:715983 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:394160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:987194124 (987.1 MB)  TX bytes:38882147 (38.8 MB)

sterome@Sterome:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
sterome@Sterome:~$ ping -c3 airvpn.org
PING airvpn.org (5.196.64.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ns334629.ip-5-196-64.eu (5.196.64.52): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=34.1 ms
64 bytes from ns334629.ip-5-196-64.eu (5.196.64.52): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=33.2 ms
64 bytes from ns334629.ip-5-196-64.eu (5.196.64.52): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=39.3 ms

--- airvpn.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.242/35.559/39.318/2.686 ms
```

And this happens when the VPN is connected:

```
sterome@Sterome:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:eb:38:c7  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:17661 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17661 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2404286 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:2404286 (2.4 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.4.22.129  P-t-P:10.4.22.129  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:3224 (3.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:36:dd:c3:34:1c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:2450:103a:a6a:5c97:d6ce:4d4a:59e/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:2450:103a:a6a:6236:ddff:fec3:341c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6236:ddff:fec3:341c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:716130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:394305 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:987220501 (987.2 MB)  TX bytes:38906803 (38.9 MB)

sterome@Sterome:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.4.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.4.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun0
62.102.148.143  192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
128.0.0.0       10.4.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
sterome@Sterome:~$ ping -c3 airvpn.org
ping: unknown host airvpn.org
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you can ping some service by it's IP address, not the canonical name, for example:

`ping -c 3 8.8.8.8`

If you can, then problem is with accessibility of your DNS. The easiest way to change it is by editing /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

But if you want it to be done every time you connect to VPN check this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/318563/how-to-push-my-own-dns-server-to-openvpn

Comment: Glad to help. Consider marking the answer as correct :-)