# OpenVPN - no internet on second device after reinstalling on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vpn

My VPN started disconnecting when I used the same VPN settings on 2 separate devices (should support up to 3 devices though).
I tried reinstalling VPN software on the 2nd device before removing all parts of it which might be the problem now.

Can installing over an existing installation cause problems?

It now works fine on the device I haven't changed anything on, but the other says I now have a VPN connection (little lock in the corner) but when I open the browser there is no internet connection.

As soon as I disconnect the VPN I get access again.

Can anyone suggest what to do, or should look at changing/deleting/reinstalling?

Any possible solution?

How do I delete/uninstall everything I might have installed for VPN that could be causing conflict, in order to reinstall without duplicate application conflict. (this might be the problem...how can I tell?)

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/a/713066/603891

Comment: Try not to shout... And make appropriate use of "?".

Comment: You can check again your encryption settings. When you do import via the GUI the GUI on 16.04 tends to set the encryption incorrectly. Set it again via GUI and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The default Openvpn configuration supports only one client per one client key. Try to generate more client keys, when you want more client connections.

The no internet access part of your question:

Try to add a following line to your iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o br-lan -j MASQUERADE
```

The `10.0.0.0` should be replaced with your **Openvpn ip address** and `br-lan` should be replaced with your **physical or virtual lan interface** (this depends on your setup).

Answer (score 0):

If you use on your devices same config and certificates you need add to server config

```
duplicate-cn
```

and restart openvpn service.
OR run openvpn service with flag

```
--duplicate-cn
```

Then you can connect to your server from 2+ clients with same configs.