# Client OpenVPN connection has no internet connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and openvpn 2.4.4. When I try to connect with the vpn I can't use the internet anymore, only the resources behind the vpn. I can't even ping 8.8.8.8 (all packets lost). Smh this only happened to me and not other people using the same script. However, this applies to 3 different devices of mine.

The following is the config content

```
dev tun
client
proto <tcp>
<ca> </ca>
<cert> </cert>
<key> </key>
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Server Authentication"
remote x.x.x.x z
redirect-gateway def1
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
keepalive 10 60
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
float
reneg-sec 3660
nobind
mute-replay-warnings
auth-user-pass
;remember_connection 0
;auto_reconnect 1
```

I have no idea anymore what is wrong here.

I did try the following solution approach:
[OpenVPN connecting but no internet access on Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655806/openvpn-connecting-but-no-internet-access-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04)

(first response)

But it does not work. When I check the box "use connection only for resources on its network" I can access the internet but I can not access the resources on my vpn network. If I dont check that box, I cant access the internet but I can access my vpn network resources.

Comment: Did it ever work? Confusing phrasing "can't use the internet anymore"

Comment: No it never did. If I check the box: internet can be used, network behind the vpn cant be used. If I dont check the box: internet cant be used, network behind the vpn can be used.

Comment: Sounds backwards. I think you need a push command, will look at my config when i turn on a real pc.

Comment: "cant use the internet anymore" means: once I run the vpn configuration file, internet can not be used. Before I ran the VPN, the internet could be normally accessed. When I run the vpn, I can access the network behind it. I just cant access the internet simultaneously.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sounds backwards? This is literally what happens. Technically it shouldn't go like this though, that's true.

Comment: When you say "set up the vpn" do you control the server or only a client? In other words, can you make changes to the server config file?

Comment: I am only a client. I cannot make any changes server side. Also, of all the people using this vpn, I am the only person this happens to. However, I have tried 3 different devices of mine (all Ubuntu 18.04) and the problem persists in all 3.

Comment: Oh. my idea won't help then. Best wishes. Might want to [edit] your question to make it clear that you are not setting up a vpn, just trying to use one, and that it never worked.

Comment: I am in contact with the admin who runs the vpn server. If you have any ideas for how to even diagnose why I cant use this, please share. Maybe he'll be open to check them out.