# Openvpn connected but internet doesnt work in Kbuntu 20.04

Tags: network-manager, internet, vpn, openvpn

I connect to Openvpn but then my internet connection is lost as I cannot load webpages. Here are some details. I use KDE plasma desktop and problem still persists.

ip route (before connecting to openvpn)

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.221 metric 100
```

ip route (after connecting to openvpn)

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s31f6 proto dhcp metric 100 
128.0.0.0/1 via 172.30.88.1 dev tun0 
141.52.8.20 via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s31f6 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6 scope link metric 1000 
172.30.88.0/22 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.91.215 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.221 metric 100
```

Below outputs are after connecting to openvpn

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8
```

Output:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.30.88.1 (172.30.88.1)  59.462 ms  59.450 ms  59.447 ms
 2  141.52.3.129 (141.52.3.129)  59.438 ms  59.427 ms  59.440 ms
 3  129.13.36.1 (129.13.36.1)  59.378 ms  59.392 ms  59.377 ms
 4  141.52.249.254 (141.52.249.254)  64.566 ms  64.472 ms  64.497 ms
 5  141.52.249.226 (141.52.249.226)  64.894 ms 141.52.249.227 (141.52.249.227)  64.895 ms  64.883 ms
 6  193.197.63.6 (193.197.63.6)  66.476 ms  33.209 ms  34.324 ms
 7  129.143.60.115 (129.143.60.115)  36.969 ms  36.943 ms 188.1.144.222 (188.1.144.222)  48.418 ms
 8  209.85.172.242 (209.85.172.242)  51.037 ms  51.057 ms 142.250.162.80 (142.250.162.80)  41.897 ms
 9  * * 108.170.252.65 (108.170.252.65)  47.951 ms
10  8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)  46.857 ms  46.789 ms  47.315 ms
```

```
route -n
```

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.30.88.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
128.0.0.0       172.30.88.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
141.52.8.20     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s31f6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
172.30.88.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6
```

I have tried this GNOME solution https://askubuntu.com/a/713066/1095090, but I cannot see openvpn connection option in my network manager. All I see is the wired network through which internet works (if not connected to openvpn)

Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue in Kubuntu20.04? Been struggling to solve this since months. Thanks

Comment: does this answer your question friend? https://askubuntu.com/questions/655806/openvpn-connecting-but-no-internet-access-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04

Comment: @osakacjupiter I use KDE plasma, and my network manager just shows my local wired network and, I'm  not able to open Openvpn network manager configurations.

Comment: i see. you are right mate. i forgot that was gnome

Comment: does using a KDE affect the network connecting issues ?

Comment: I think you can use GNOME apps in KDE as long as you have GTK libraries installed on your system. I don't think KDE affect the network connecting

Comment: @OrganicMarble I connect via terminal  `sudo openvpn --config /home/user08/vpn/fileman.ovpn`